# Error messages when compiling old fortran code

Tags: compilation, fortran

I am trying to compile a code that hasn't been developed with the newest standards in mind. I am using the *gfortran* compiler and get a few errors that I can't correct.

A partner of mine uses the Intel Visual Fortran compiler in MS Visual Studio and doesn't get any errors. Below are the relevant sections of code and their errors. Insight into any of these would be greatly appreciated.

**Error 1:**

```
flow.for:63.63:

 3      *gjmh_old(j)*abs(gjmh_old(j))/2.0d0/dens_fjmh(j)  )         
                                                           1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

**Corresponding code:**

```
sum_dpjmh_old= 1.0/2.0*(dens_jmh(j)+dens_old(j))*grav*(dzc(j)/2.0d0) !!!!
 1    + ( gavg_old(j)*gavg_old(j)/dens_mom(j)
 1       -gjmh_old(j)*gjmh_old(j)/dmom_jmh(j)     )
 3    + 1.0/2.0*
 3     ( fric(j)*dzc(j)/2.0/dhyd(j)
 3      *gavg_old(j)*abs(gavg_old(j))/2.0d0/dens_fric(j)
 3      +fjmh(j)*dzc(j)/2.0/dhyd(j)
 3      *gjmh_old(j)*abs(gjmh_old(j))/2.0d0/dens_fjmh(j)  )
```

**Error 2:**

```
flow.for:78.13:

 1    + ( gavg(j)*gavg(j)/dens_momn(j)                              
         1
Error: Missing exponent in real number at (1)
```

**Corresponding Code:**

```
sum_dpjmh = 1.0/2.0*(dens_jmhn(j)+dens_ch(j))*grav*(dzc(j)/2.0d0) !!!!
 1    + ( gavg(j)*gavg(j)/dens_momn(j)
 1       -gjmh(j)*gjmh(j)/dmom_jmhn(j)     )
 3    + 1.0/2.0*
 3     ( fric(j)*(dzc(j)/2.0)/dhyd(j)
 3      *gavg(j)*abs(gavg(j))/2.0d0/dens_ch(j)
 3      + fjmh(j)*(dzc(j)/2.0)/dhyd(j)
 3      *gjmh(j)*abs(gjmh(j))/2.0d0/dens_jmhn(j)  )
```

**Error 3:**

```
flow.for:684.72:

 3           /dens_fjmh(j) )                                        
                                                                    1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

**Corresponding code:**

```
gjmh(j) = gjmh_old(j) + dt/dzc(j)*(
 1           phi*2.0d0*(pjmh(j)-p(j))
 1         + (1.0-phi)*2.0d0*(pjmh_old(j)-p_old(j))
 1         - 2.0d0*( gavg_old(j)*gavg_old(j)/dens_mom(j)
 1          -gjmh_old(j)*gjmh_old(j)/dmom_jmh(j) )
 4         - dens_jmh(j)*grav*dzc(j)
 3         - fjmh(j)*dzc(j)/2.0d0/dhyd(j)*gjmh_old(j)*abs(gjmh_old(j))
 3           /dens_fjmh(j) )
```

Comment: I wonder if your code is in the non-standard *tab source form* (http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-210A9DD0-6D82-400C-BC17-709506A5E35E.htm#GUID-210A9DD0-6D82-400C-BC17-709506A5E35E) which the Intel compiler understands.  It would surprise me not a jot if gfortran doesn't understand it.

Comment: It appears that gfortran will accept tabs on continuation lines under some compilation options: "By default, tabs are accepted as whitespace, but tabs are not members of the Fortran Character Set. For continuation lines, a tab followed by a digit between 1 and 9 is supported."  Option `-Wno-tabs` will cause a warning to be issued if a tab is encountered.

Comment: The standard fixed-form layout for continuing lines is continuation characters characters in column 6. With regular statements in column 7 or higher.

Comment: you have lines past col 72. `The sum_..` line is near 72 already, adding 7 spaces in front makes it too long. Set your compiler to allow longer lines, or (my preference) add a continuation to break the long lines.

Comment: ...counting carefully `D0)` is chopped off, leaving you with a syntactically correct expression except for an unbalanced parenthesis, hence the error..

Comment: If this is the only line too long, then adding adding continuation is best.  If the legacy code has many too long lines, the gfortran option to extend the line lengths is `-ffixed-line-length-none`.

Comment: Just for info: you'll probably find that the ifort version has a -80 or -132 parameter in the compilation.

Comment: This was just a line length issue that I missed since the was on the previous lines not the lines noted as having the error. Thanks for all the suggestions. Now I just need to figure out the best way to replace expressions in the format statements i.e. format(i3,<nzones+1>(1x,i4),...)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your code is not well formatted. If you are trying to use fixed format, you should follow the request of fixed format, as http://nf.nci.org.au/training/FortranBasic/slides/slides.005.html.
Or following instructions in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Fixed_layout_and_punched_cards:

> Column 1 contains *, ! or C for comments.
>
> Column 6 for continuation.

Another way is to convert fixed format to free format, but since your code is not well formatted, most converter may be not working well.